# Is storing user IP in database necessary?

Tags: database

Do I need to store user IP with any record he can put into database?

- my public web application stores a lot of comments, announcements, stories, articles and such,
- you have to be registered and logged in to write anything,
- you can be logged more than once (other browser or device), so the user's IP can vary.

Solutions:

1. To have `ip` column in every table.
2. Ignore IP completely - why even bother? Does this value count in trail - I think not.
3. `ip` per user session - but how to manage that in long term (session can end and its data disappear)?

Comment: If you don't need it, you don't have to store it. Often if someone needs this kind of detail they'll look in web server logs where this information may be kept.

Comment: @user814064, do you suggest that IP stored in database would be just a copy of already stored information in server log file and we shouldn't bother to do it? I wonder if log files are stored enough long to trust them ;)

Comment: You can store them for as long you want. We zip up our IIS logs and save them forever. An additional consideration is that IP Addresses are in some sense private, and if you put them into a permanent database you might feel obligated to tell users that you're storing the data. And if you have a security hole some day too much personal information can cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If you got the username, store this (or the users id). Storing the IP would be a good idea if unregistered users/guests could make comments, as a way to track who did what. Wikipedia displays the username for registered users but the ip for not-signed-in users.

Comment: Each record in database, with data provided by user, has the `user_id` column which reference to one and only specific user account.

Comment: Then you won't need the IP and you can use this user_id.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why you would like to keep track of the users IP. If none of them make sense to you, them there is no reason to. You could:

- Limit login attempts from a given ip
- Allow the users to log in only from a 'safe' (previously added) ip
- Allow not registered users to do things (in that way you would
  identify them by IP)
- Log to the user his/hers last IP logins, so that he could identify
  suspect behaviour

These are the ones I can think of right now - very specific they are, though. Most commom scenarios, there's just no need to do it.

Comment: Authorization is and individual case which has its own rules (mentioned by you in points 1, 2 and 4) and is not part of my question (but thank you very much for pointing it out!). Not registered users (point 3) cannot change anything in database.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to consider the **Privacy Policy** of your Web Application as you are storing sensitive data of a user.

Can you tell why storing IP Address of user is required in your web application anyways?

Comment: Is not required, yet, and we're thinking, should we change it or not. Is this information (ip) worth anything.